# Is there a way to do automated decompilation with ILSpy?

Tags: decompiler, ilspy

We have a rather large third party product which contains a lot of C# DLLs and is updated every month or so.  While the decompiler does only a 98% job where it can't get everything, it's good enough for my purposes for the occasional comparative analysis.

Would there be a way to do command line decompilation so that I could decompile every month's release and save it in an archive in an automated manner?

Perhaps something like

```
ilspy /f phantasmagorical.dll /s c:\myapp\archive\mar2020

/f - file to decompile, .dll, .exe, etc.
/s - save location
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ILSpy.exe is meant for interactive use and doesn't have anything like that.

You can instead use the [ilspycmd](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/tree/master/ICSharpCode.ILSpyCmd) command line tool:

```
ilspycmd phantasmagorical.dll -p -o c:\myapp\archive\mar2020
```

You could also use the [ICSharpCode.Decompiler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.Decompiler/) nuget package to programatically run the decompiler.