Automation of decompilation of files using dotPeek?
I use dotPeek for decompilation of dll-s which are automatically generated by a software. For some tests I need the classes inside these dll-s and for this reason I found that dotPeek could generate a C# project out of the dll which is good news because the other alternative I used was by manually accessing the code for each class I need in the dll-s by clicking to go to the definition in Visual Studio which generated the file with the class by request. But still, in order dotPeek to generate the project I need again manually to open the program, to right-click on the preloaded dll and to select "Extract to project...". I need an automated way this to be done since often there are changes in data and therefore - change in these generated dlls. Maybe a way starting for exporting to project by the command line? Or maybe other software?
Edit: there was a suggestion the ILSpy addon to be used but it is forbidden to be used within the organization I work for.

Do you need the classes as source code? Why not just reference the generated dll from your tests?

@JonasH unfortunately I cannot - the test framework does not have access to some libraries used in these classes. So I use a script that strips down a little bit before I apply this code to the tests.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60856709/is-there-a-way-to-do-automated-decompilation-with-ilspy

So you not just change/mock dependencies but decompile the code, change it and then test the changed and recompiled code? That sounds like trustworthy test.

Having a script go in and edit source code to make it testable sounds quite fragile. Are you sure this is the best way to approach your problem? This smells a bit like a XY-problem.

@HansPassant thanks for this solution! Unfortunately ILspy is not allowed to be used within the organization I work for and it will not work for me. But still, you can post it as an answer to my question and I'll upvote it.

@JonasH, Ralf as I said, there are some libraries which cannot be used unless the software which makes these dlls is used. The tests are used for similar issues but they cannot be used with this software. I know it is not a perfect solution and if you could suggest better, I'll appreciate it. But for now this is what I am stuck on.
