Looking for a CLI utility that converts dotnet framework assembly to a dotnet standard assembly
I have a set of trivial DotNet framework assemblies ("dlls") that I wish to convert to dotnet stanard 2.0.
By "trivial" I mean that they contain Enum definitions and trivial interface classes, no business logic whatsoever.
I am not interested in re-compiling these assemblies (let's assume for now that the code is unreachable), I just wish to convert them.
Didn't find any such tool yet, and I thought I'll check out this place before I go ahead and invent such a utility. Someone MUST have built it already...right?
Tried Google, mostly.

I don't think that such a tool exists. Easier to recompile (remember all the compile/publish/... steps can be done from the CLI). If you have lost the source code then there are de-compilers around (I use ilspy, and there is a CLI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60868454/67392)

That doesn't sound like a tool that most people would want/need - most people would just change the csproj to change the build TFM/TFMs, and rebuild; if the source is lost: if the content is as simple as you describe, maybe just decompile it back out to C#?

There are couple ways to do what you want (in fact there are more ways but the described below are most easy to integrate)
API Surface code generation
If you need to provide a crossplatform library with API contracts, without implementation (if I understood you correctly) you can use this tool https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/tree/main/src/Compatibility/GenAPI
Running .net4.5 under mono
If you need to run some net4.5 code then probably try this way:
Create .NET Standard Project.
Ensure Mono is installed on all target platforms. This setup allows cross-platform execution of .NET Framework 4.5 code in a .NET Standard 2.0 project using Mono.
Place your .NET Framework 4.5 DLL in the project directory and write  interop class
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyCrossPlatformLibrary
{
    public class Net45Interop
    {
        private const string MonoPath = "/usr/bin/mono";

        [DllImport(MonoPath, EntryPoint = "mono_jit_init")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonoInit(string domain);

        [DllImport(MonoPath, EntryPoint = "mono_domain_assembly_open")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonoOpenAssembly(IntPtr domain, string assemblyPath);

        [DllImport(MonoPath, EntryPoint = "mono_class_from_name")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonoGetClass(IntPtr assembly, string namespaceName, string className);

        [DllImport(MonoPath, EntryPoint = "mono_class_get_method_from_name")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonoGetMethod(IntPtr classHandle, string methodName, int paramCount);

        [DllImport(MonoPath, EntryPoint = "mono_runtime_invoke")]
        private static extern IntPtr MonoInvoke(IntPtr method, IntPtr obj, IntPtr[] param, out IntPtr exc);

        private IntPtr _domain;

        public Net45Interop()
        {
            _domain = MonoInit("MyDomain");
        }

        public void ExecuteNet45Code(string assemblyPath, string namespaceName, string className, string methodName)
        {
            IntPtr assembly = MonoOpenAssembly(_domain, assemblyPath);
            IntPtr classHandle = MonoGetClass(assembly, namespaceName, className);
            IntPtr method = MonoGetMethod(classHandle, methodName, 0);
            IntPtr exception;
            MonoInvoke(method, IntPtr.Zero, null, out exception);

            if (exception != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception occurred while invoking method");
            }
        }
    }
}

Try build and run - should work
namespace MyCrossPlatformLibrary
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Net45Interop interop = new Net45Interop();
            interop.ExecuteNet45Code("path/to/your/net45.dll", "YourNamespace", "YourClass", "YourMethod");
        }
    }
}

